# jQuery load into inputfield?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load some texts from an external page into my current page inside an input text field.

I am using this code:

```
$( "#input2" ).load( "external.php #somediv" );
```

however, this doesn't load anything into my input field!

I tried to load the same data/content from the same page into a div in my current page and it works fine:

```
$( "#div2" ).load( "external.php #somediv" );
```

is there something that I need to do?

I even tried this but i'm sure this is wrong:

```
$( "#input2" ).val(load( "external.php #somediv" ));
```

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: an `<input>` tag can't have children. You might try using a `<textarea>`.

Comment: What is #somediv? also remove the space  before #

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$.get()`

```
$.get("/path/to/html", function(html) {
  $("#input2").val( $(html).find("#somediv").text() )
})
```